# How can I create a model like this? (see image)

Tags: modeling

[image: Man figure]
[image: Other figures]

How can I create the models like in the image quickly?

When I rigged a figure I made and tried to animate it, the arms and hands were not bending correctly. I used separate objects for the head, hands, abdomen and so on, and then combined them using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>.

Comment: you need to know and consider topology very well, when you wish to animate arms and legs, then also use weights wisely. Please show what you did and/or share your test file on http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ then edit your question and paste the provided link.

Comment: The fastesr way may be using metaballs, convert them to mesh and parent to armature with automatic weights.

Comment: @PaulGonet Thanks! I never really tried metaballs before but I just found out they do pretty nice job!

Answer (score 1):

There may be multiple ways of achieving this but I will be using metaballs for now as they offer a quick solution. Add metaballs on the fly, adjust, when you get an acceptable mesh, convert it to mesh ( alt + c), sculpt, add armature and pose it to achieve the final look.